# Dynamically change the background image in CSS for different posts in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to change the background image called in CSS dynamically for different posts? In short, I am looking to show the featured image of a post in WordPress as background?

```
background: #253340 url('assets/images/blog/post-2.jpg') no-repeat 50% top;
```

I did try this one find on this forum but didn't work.

```
background: #253340 url(<?php echo $variable_holding_img_url; ?>) no-repeat 50% top;
```

Comment: it should work as long as that style tag is inside php file and that variable which you are using having some dynamic value.

Comment: have you tried above code in your php file or css file ? just tell this so that i can give you exact answer ... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$image_url = 'my_default_image_url.jpg'; // fallback image url

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'large' )[0]; // large or full or custom size
}
?>

<div style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image_url; ?>');"></div>
```

---

### Function References

- [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/)
- [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

Answer (score 2):

If your theme supports post thumbnails you can do the following as long as the css code is in the template and not in a seperated css file

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <div id="custom-bg" style="background: #253340 url('<?= $image[0] ?>') no-repeat 50% top;')">

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) returns a image tag, not an url.

Comment: edited with the right function. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

No, above code will break your work as it will return all exact image tag and data. You should use like this way.

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
<!-- div that holds the background -->
<div style="background: #253340 url('<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>') no-repeat 50% top;">
    <!-- some other content -->
</div>
```

And it will produce exact out put.

Note: this code will go inside php file not in your css file.

Comment: [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) returns an array. You have to use `echo $image_url[0]` for the url.

Comment: Thanks! Akram. The code works but the featured image has reduced.

Comment: sorry i forget to mention just change like this $image_url[0] .... thanks I am changing my solution also check that updated code ...